# MySQL ECONNREFUSED Error when connecting from Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord

I've been getting the below error when attempting to connect from Javascript:
`Error connecting to database: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306`
`at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '::1', port: 3306, …}`

This is my JS Code

```
// create connection to database
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.dbHost,
    user: config.dbUser,
    password: config.dbPassword,
    database: config.dbName,
  });
  
  // connect to database
  con.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error connecting to database:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
  });
```

And other stuff that's relevant

```
const config = require('./config.json');
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

```
{
    "token": "",
    "prefix": "!",
    "clientId": "",
    "guildId": "",
    "db_host": "ip:3306",
    "db_user": "user",
    "db_pass": "password",
    "db_name": "db name",
    "partyCodes": {
      "ALP": "Australian Labor Party",
      "LIB": "Liberal Party of Australia",
      "AWP": "Australian Workers Party",
      "NAT": "National Party of Australia",
      "LCP": "Liberal Democratic Party",
      "SFF": "Shooters, Fishers and Farmers Party",
      "SIT": "Sustainable Australia",
      "JAF": "Justice Alliance of Australia"
    },
    "campaignChannelId": ""
  }
```

Tried adding users for my IP with all privileges. Added firewall perms too.

Comment: Connection Refused generally means the the host you're trying to connect to isn't running MySQL.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular im trying to connect from a remote host, never done this before because i usually connect from localhost. I'm just using the Digital Ocean IPv4 plus  SQL port. Would this work? Also created a user for my IP with all privileges and modified firewall. Is there also any way to see what specifically is wrong?

Comment: host: should be host and not port. 
add a port variable separately

Comment: @AmirSaleem I tried this, same thing:
```
var dbconfig = {  
    server: '159.223.66.254',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sammy',
            password: 'password'
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: 'Campaign Data',
        port: '3306' //your port number
    }
}; 

const con = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);

  // connect to database
  con.connect((err) => {
 if (err) {
   console.log('Error connecting to database:', err);
   return;
 }
 console.log('Connected to database');
  });
```

Comment: I have a feeling you didn't provide the actual Json file. 
If you did, on localhost, 
username = 'root'
password = ''
host = 'localhost'

{
    "db_host": "localhost",
    "db_user": "root",
    "db_pass": "",
  }